# How to get each value in combobox over to sql database

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, combobox

Okay so here's my code. Everything works and saves to the database.
Though, it only stores the current value that's displayed in the combobox.
I want it to store all 3 values, for each value has its own checkboxes.
How would I go about coding something that saves each of the 3 values and the corresponding checkboxes to the database(sql)?

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qXMw.png)
    , Code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into cloggingInfo(Date, PID, Operator, Type)values('"+labelTime.Text+"', '" + cboStatePid.Text + "', '" + cboStateOperator.Text + "', '" + cboStateType.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Start added succesfully");
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            AddToListView();
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48464293/edit) your question and add your code as text

Comment: Gah! The sql injection vulnerability... it burns us!

Comment: Consider putting the SqlCommand in a using block, rather than explicitly calling dispose. That way it gets disposed even if there's an exception. Also, the SqlConnection is also disposable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "combobox.SelectedItem" or "combobox.SelectedValue". If your combobox is filled with datasource you need to define "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" for it.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into cloggingInfo(Date, PID, Operator, Type)values('"+labelTime.Text+"', '" + cboStatePid.SelectedItem+ "', '" + cboStateOperator.SelectedItem+ "', '" + cboStateType.SelectedItem+ "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Start added succesfully");
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            AddToListView();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the combo box items for each combo box as shown below and then save it.

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder comboBox1Items = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in comboBox1.Items)
            {
                comboBox1Items.Append(item + " ");
            }
           string cb1Items = comboBox1Items.ToString();
        }`